# How Does One Place a Cursor in Between Characters in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, text-editor

I am having trouble figuring out how to place my cursor in between characters in the text editor of Visual Studio Community 2022 Version 17.8.4.

For example, when I attempt to place my cursor in between "c" and "o", in the word "cout", it highlights the "o" character. Therefore, when I try to edit the word, it ends up replacing the letter instead of allowing me to input a letter in between "c" and "o".

Comment: I found out how to do what my post was asking. Incase this helps anyone, in order to place your cursor in between characters on Visual Studio 2022, you can press the "insert" button on your keyboard and clicking the left mouse button where you want your cursor to be placed.

Comment: You might want to click the Answer your Own Question link and put your findings in an Answer!

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else finding this, it's not Visual-Studio-specifc, it applies to every text input box in Windows.

As noted in comments, the way to get back to a thin cursor is to press `INS` or `Insert` on your keyboard.

As to why it happens... When you're *inserting* text, you're creating new characters when you type and they are placed between existing characters.

The alternative mode is to *overwrite* text. When you type, existing characters are replaced.

`Insert` switches back and forth between these two modes.

The solid box when in *overwrite* mode is showing you which character will be wiped out when you type a new one.